# How to API forwarding GPU acceleration with KVM GPU?

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, gpu

I am finding myself unable to fins some resources about how to use setup AF<sup>1</sup> in a KVM Vitural Machine, Thus the question is how I would be able to setup AF GPU acceleration in a KVM (linux) virtual Machine. (Note Is requied Vulkan & OpenGL support)

1: As defined here: [Blog Post](https://adamgradzki.com/2020/04/06/faster-virtual-machines-linux/)